# Clarification on academic and academia tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at the tags on this question during an edit: [How to enter the GPA of a degree program on a job application?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/180101/how-to-enter-the-gpa-of-a-degree-program-on-a-job-application)

It includes [academic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic), which I thought might not apply. My assumption was that was going to be for questions about actually working in academia, not about academic qualifications. Indeed, the only other question using that tag is about an application for a teaching job.

However, when I went to check, I found that there is also a tag for [academia](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia). Most of its six questions also deal with working in academia.

So there are two tags that are maybe supposed to mean the same thing and I'm not sure what should happen here. Should we:

1. Make these tags synonyms and remove it from the above question?
2. Make these tags distinct so that one is about working in academia but the other is about academic qualifications, and retag the questions accordingly?
3. Make these tags synonyms but also make a new 'academic-qualifications" tag?
4. Something else?

Obviously these tags need usage guidance whatever else happens. Even if most folks using the tags don't look at it, it'd be good to know what tags are supposed to mean when doing editing.

Comment: I think [tag:academia] should be about working in academia, and [tag:academia] for something. Maybe [tag:academia] can be renamed to academic-qualifications?

Answer (score 8):

A tag for academia didn't really belong on [How to enter the GPA of a degree program on a job application?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/180101/how-to-enter-the-gpa-of-a-degree-program-on-a-job-application), removed.

The other question using it ([What does "Principal Position" means in the CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177797/what-does-principal-position-means-in-the-cv)) should have just used [academia](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia).

Since there's no need to fragment these tags, I've merged "academic" into [academia](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia) and created a synonym.

If you run into similar cases in future, with just a handful of posts, it's probably fine to just correct the tags yourself. A tag synonym is probably even overkill here since it won't come up that often. High rep users can [suggest tag synonyms](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) as well though.